# GDB can't access/step into file for debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, clion

I'm trying to debug a piece of code, but GDB seems to be completely unable to read a specific single file. Any breakpoint inside that file or with content that refers to that file (like instantiating a class from that file) is skipped immediately upon reaching.

From what I could gather on Google, this is a bug that appeared first in GDB in the early 2000s, disappeared on 2005 but still happens somewhat rarely, and has no documented solution.

[This is the affected file](https://gist.github.com/ranisalt/db9a3b410d37f418f59e) and this file and it's header(with only declarations) are the only files from [this project](https://github.com/ranisalt/map-generator/tree/9b74be4d10a746016ba84322c88e5d3d06797f4e) that can not be accessed with GDB.

The project is being compiled using CMake and is using the flags `-g3 -O0`, so I think there are no missing debug information.

I'm using GDB via my IDE, CLion 1.0.3, but using the terminal renders the same problems.

Comment: This usually winds up being a problem with one file not getting the `-g` somehow, or not being rebuilt, or something like that.  More rarely there are other reasons.  You can check to see if the `.o` file has debug info by using `readelf -WS` and looking for the various debug sections.

Comment: @TomTromey I did it and the file has some sections named like "debug_line", "debug_str" and "debug_macro", so I guess it's correct. I also did a full rebuild of the file (removed build dir, rerun cmake .. then rebuild) and it did not work.

Comment: Ok.  Next I would check the final executable to make sure the debug info from this file is there.  You can use `readelf -wi` on the executable for this.  You can search for the specific CU by file name.  After that the next thing to check is if gdb is rejecting the CU for some reason.  For this you want `set complaints 10000` in gdb, followed by `file` to open the executable.

Comment: I used `readelf -wi` and it couldn't find references to the class I'm trying to debug. With the complaints setting on GDB, i get lots of `During symbol reading, unexpected tag in read_type_die: 'DW_TAG_rvalue_reference_type'.` errors.

Comment: I'm afraid you have hit a bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14441